# Ways to alter the standard /LaTeX macro

Tags: macros, formatting

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm trying to include [image]
in a document. Is there a way to spread the spelling? I'm using the standard /LaTeX and noticed the A is too close to the L.

Comment: It was developed with Computer Modern in mind. Perhaps use `{\rmfamily\LaTeX}`.

Comment: Which compiler? (pdftex.lualatex. etc.). Which fonts? Makes a difference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you look in ltnews.cls (same folder as article.cls) You will see no less than 5 variant `\LaTeX` macros tuned to different fonts:  `% The LaTeX logo for use with Palatino. ` `% The LaTeX logo for use with Utopia.`  `% The LaTeX logo for use with Helvetica.`  `% The LaTeX logo for use with Grotesk.`  `% The LaTeX logo for use with CMSS.`

Comment: Look at the `metalogo` package.